# Why javascript replace function argument using regular expression can not differentiate between dot and underscore?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created simple html page to replace `rcm.Name` to `rcm.Name1` . But it's also changing `rcm_Name` to `rcm.Name1`. I don't know why this global search is changing `rcm_Name` to `rcm.Name1` as well.

**HTML:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var txt = str.replace(/rcm.Name/g, "rcm.Name" + "1");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">rcm.Name is the id. rcm_Name is the name of the element. Here is same Id rcm.Name</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions `.` stands for any character. If you want it to match specifically dots you should escape it with a `\`. In your case `var txt = str.replace(/rcm\.Name/g,"rcm.Name"+"1");` will do the job.

Comment: so how to replace ?

Answer (score 1):

In regex `.` matches any single character.

Use `\.` to match the `period` charactar as you really wanted